# Laravel 4 artisan migrate install

Tags: mysql, laravel-4

I'm trying to migrate a very basic app from Laravel 3 to Laravel 4. It looks very easy but for some reason the following command is not working.

```
php artisan migrate:install
```

Following this tutorial: http://laravel.com/docs/quick#installation it seems like we don't need to install the artisan anymore. So I tried just running

```
php artisan migrate
```

But I always get the error

> [ErrorException]
>    Undefined index: collation

My database.php:

```
'fetch' => PDO::FETCH_CLASS,
'default' => 'mysql',
'connections' => array(

    'sqlite' => array(
        'driver'   => 'sqlite',
        'database' => __DIR__.'/../database/production.sqlite',
        'prefix'   => '',
    ),
    'mysql' => array(
        'driver'   => 'mysql',
        'host'     => '127.0.0.1',
        'database' => 'wepromoters_db',
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => '',
        'charset'  => 'utf8',
        'prefix'   => '',
    ),

    'pgsql' => array(
        'driver'   => 'pgsql',
        'host'     => 'localhost',
        'database' => 'database',
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => '',
        'charset'  => 'utf8',
        'prefix'   => '',
        'schema'   => 'public',
    ),

    'sqlsrv' => array(
        'driver'   => 'sqlsrv',
        'host'     => 'localhost',
        'database' => 'database',
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => '',
        'prefix'   => '',
    ),

),

    'redis' => array(

    'cluster' => true,

    'default' => array(
        'host'     => '127.0.0.1',
        'port'     => 6379,
        'database' => 0,
    ),

),
```

My migration:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users',function($table){
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->string('type');
        $table->timestamps();

    });
}
```

Lastly the db is working fine with my Laravel 3 app

What is going on?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Laravel 4 php artisan migration not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17538609/laravel-4-php-artisan-migration-not-working)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this thread](http://forums.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?id=6774) on the Laravel forums, a `collation` parameter is now required in the database configuration.

Try it with this (notice the extra "collation" parameter after the "charset" one) :

```
'mysql' => array(
        'driver'   => 'mysql',
        'host'     => '127.0.0.1',
        'database' => 'wepromoters_db',
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => '',
        'charset'  => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'   => '',
    ),
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I could not find this by my self :(

Answer (score 0):

Laravel 4 is entirely different with Laravel 3, So use laravel 4 commands to migrate your table. I don't know exactly but you can try with this command:

```
php artisan make:migration create_users_table(Enter)
```

So, we created default users table and have to create our table:

```
php artisan make:migration create_YourTableName_table -- create YourTableName
```

Then, check your file in "migration/YourTableName.php" by opening it.

Now, you can write your code under the "Run Migration Block".

Finally, Run this command to migrate your table.

```
php artisan migrate
```

It will migrate your table with in span of time.